# Shell scripting: Why does only the "-" hyphen throw an error?

Tags: terminal, script, command-line

### Goal: Cleaning up

Selectively truncate filenames in my nvALT notes folder. I tried using a productivity blogger's suggestion (which eludes me after a thorough search) to prepend `^ > - +` to filenames, but it's not working for me. It's time to clean house! However, I need to make sure I don't lop off any alpha characters on filenames that do *not* use those prefixes. Plus I'm learning scripting and think it's fun!

### Shell script

Here's what I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/dropbox/notes_test

for f in *; do
  FILENAME=$(basename "$f")
  DIRNAME=$(dirname "$f")
  if [[ "$f" == \^\ * ]]; then
    mv "$f" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME:2}"
  fi
  if [[ "$f" == \+\ * ]]; then
    mv "$f" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME:2}"
  fi
  if [[ "$f" == \>\ * ]]; then
    mv "$f" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME:2}"
  fi
  if [[ "$f" == \-\ * ]]; then
    mv "$f" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME:2}"
  fi
done
```

### Problem: The hyphen

Here's the command line input and error message. I get one of these for each filename beginning with "- ".

```
DEV0041:scripts n$ ./truncate.sh
basename: illegal option --  
usage: basename string [suffix]
       basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]
dirname: illegal option --  
usage: dirname path
mv: illegal option --  
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

### Question: Why does the hyphen—and *only* the hyphen—throw an error?

And how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the man page for `mv`, the first (and possibly second) argument on the command line, if it begins with a `-`, is an option and not a file. Only `-f | -i | -n` are allowed options.

Simplest way is not to use `-` in a file name—it will confuse other command line programs—given that prepending `-` is a workaround for something else I would just not use that character.

If this is not an option, you can rewrite the `mv` commands like this

```
mv ./"$f" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME:2}"
```

or (a bit more generic because it then also works for absolute paths)

```
mv -- "$f" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME:2}"
```

Another option (and is what I would do for any bash script longer than a few lines) is write in a scripting language like perl or python - in this case they solve the problem by their move functions not passing the filenames to `mv`

Comment: It is not an option in this case because I've already created the files. But I am noting your precaution for the future.

Comment: Note that filenames that begin with "-" are likely to confuse other scripts as well as your own, and ">" will cause the file contents to be overwritten if you ever forget to quote/escape it on the command line. I'd pick different conventions, or you're likely to have ongoing problems.

Comment: Certainly, @GordonDavisson. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: I'm having an issue where it deletes filenames beginning with hyphens, e.g., `- runnx - IDEAS.txt` @Mark

Comment: It's also deleting files that don't begin with "-"... I'm going to follow your advice and seek a solution using a different language.

Comment: I am keeping this answer as valid because of the good explanation of why the hyphen is a problem. It answers my questions in spite of not solving my problem. But that just means I need to ask a different question to get to the heart of my problem.